# ASP.net Session Clear

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, session

I have a site and on the login page, on `Page_Load`, it clears the `Session`. I've tried:

```
Session.Clear()
Session.RemoveAll()
Session.Abandon()
```

Then once the login page is filled in and submit button is clicked, it then adds two values:

```
Session.Add("ref", ref)
Session.Add("date", datetxt)
```

On the next page, I've got an if statement set up:

```
If Session.Item("ref") = Nothing Then
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
End If
```

However, when it just keeps redirecting back to login, instead of loading, even though I've added Session "Ref" value.

Can you help please?

Comment: I did try and indent the code by four spaces but it hasn't worked, sorry.

Comment: have u added ispostback checking in page load.

Comment: Are you attempting to authenticate that the user has logged in before allowing them to access a given page?

Comment: @user2622875 can you add you `pageload` event of `login.aspx` page to here?

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya Hi, Here is the code. `    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Session.RemoveAll()
        Session.Clear()
        Session.Abandon()
        
    End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your OnLoad code to only clear the session when that login page is called for the first time, *not* on postback:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
   If Not IsPostback Then
      Session.RemoveAll() 
      Session.Clear() 
      Session.Abandon() 
   End If
End Sub
```

You were abandoning every session, including the one you just wrote that login data to. The Abandon happens when the current page is unloaded (has finished processing).

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the explanation as well! I thought Session.Abandon() would happen at the point the page loaded. It's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

Make slight change in your `Login.aspx` page code  and clear all session variables in side `ispostback` false condition.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
   If Not IsPostback Then
      Session.RemoveAll() 
      Session.Clear() 
      Session.Abandon() 
   End If
  End Sub
```